# Alt key wipes up labels in list view in xamarin forms uwp app?

Tags: listview, uwp, xamarin.forms, label, alt

We observed that in xamarin forms UWP app when alt key is pressed all the labels inside listview control are wiped out. Is this a known issue in xamarin forms?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug on the [Xamarin Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44973) which has similar behaviour. I don't see anything mentioned about the ALT key however. But it seems that in various scenarios the labels are wiped blank.

So yes, this is a known issue, it's probably best to keep track of the progress in the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported and fixed for next release.

See [this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57432) bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I found it only happens on labels that use wrapping. May not be suitable for all situations but a temporary work around for me was to use `LineBreakMode="NoWrap"`